# Splitting multiple values data in a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

How do I split/ separate a string of data in a single cell in product ID:

Apologies.. it is rather challenging to explain my situation and I am unable to post a pic. Could you kindly visit the below link to view the screenshot pls.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDOU9.png

Comment: Unclear how you want it split but try text to columns?

Comment: yes, please provide more clarity on how you want to split the data, because your examples are all different. Then we can know if [text-to-columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-names-by-using-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-2cd989db-2b1f-4d89-b17b-534250ff9905) will work, or perhaps even a formula.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Text-to-column does not work as the data would turn out to be a continuous string. See what I mean:

"1-12345605-456789"

Comment: I've updated more a more accurate scenario to my question above. Appreciate if you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If your sample data is column A and B, you could use this formula and drag down.  I'm assuming that "a" is on the same row as "1-13456" and "9-52364" is on the row just below it.

Place this in C2 (assuming headers): `=if(and(a3="",b3<>"",a2<>""),b2&b3,"")`

And drag down.

Comment: No. They are in the same cell. Meaning 1-123456 is on top of 9-52364  in the same cell in Row "A" Column "Product ID".